# How can I keep an SQL database values up to date with an APIs values?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have an SQL database that I am using to store the contents of a very large API (~3 mil results) because I have to make several queries to it for data analytics, so it would be too costly to have to call the API to do this. I currently have the API data up to about a month ago stored, but I need a way for it to stay up to date with the API data.

The API I am trying to use is the Texas Mixed Beverage report: https://data.texas.gov/dataset/Mixed-Beverage-Gross-Receipts/naix-2893

New results are constantly added, and the values of some of the columns change as well. My plan to update the data was to have a script when the user loads our web page that runs and checks if the most recent month's data is in the database, if not it gets that whole month of data and updates/inserts it, then does the same for following months until it finds a match.

This did not work that well and I ended up with duplicates in my database, not sure why. Any help or tips is appreciated! Here is the script:

```
function update_mixed_bev($conn)
{
    $last_date = date('Y-m-d');

    $count = 0;
    // if not in db
    while ($count == 0) {
        // get most recent entry to mixed bev report
        $url = 'https://data.texas.gov/resource/naix-2893.json?$limit=1&$where=obligation_end_date_yyyymmdd%20<=%20%27' . $last_date . '%27&$order=obligation_end_date_yyyymmdd%20DESC';
        $json = file_get_contents($url);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);

        $row = $data[0];

        // query to see if data exists in db
        $location_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_address']);
        $location_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_name']);
        $record_end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['obligation_end_date_yyyymmdd']));
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mixed_bev_data WHERE location_address='" . $location_address . "' AND record_end_date='" . $record_end_date . "' AND location_name='" . $location_name . "' AND beer_receipts=" . $row['beer_receipts'] . " AND total_receipts=" . $row['total_receipts'];

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $count = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];

        if ($count == 0) {
            $url = 'https://data.texas.gov/resource/naix-2893.json?$where=obligation_end_date_yyyymmdd%20=%20%27' . $record_end_date . '%27&$order=obligation_end_date_yyyymmdd%20DESC';
            $json = file_get_contents($url);
            $data = json_decode($json, true);

            // for each of month data
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $taxpayer_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['taxpayer_name']);
                $location_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_name']);
                $location_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_address']);
                $location_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_city']);
                $location_state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_state']);
                $location_zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['location_zip']);
                $record_end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row['obligation_end_date_yyyymmdd']));
                $beer_receipts = intval($row['beer_receipts']);
                $total_receipts = intval($row['total_receipts']);

                $sql = "INSERT INTO mixed_bev_data (taxpayer_name, location_name, location_address, location_city, location_state, location_zip, record_end_date, beer_receipts, total_receipts)
VALUES ('$taxpayer_name', '$location_name', '$location_address', '$location_city', '$location_state', '$location_zip', '$record_end_date', $beer_receipts, $total_receipts)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE beer_receipts = $beer_receipts, total_receipts = $total_receipts, time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();";

                if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            }

        }

        $last_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($record_end_date . ' - 1 day'));

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can reliably keep an up-to-date copy of their data without some special arrangement with the dataset owner whom could provide incremental logging information for example. I suggest you just download the whole file periodically.

Comment: you should run daily updates on the server side with a separate script like bash or so perl python or others everything that can be start at 3 in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. It's apparent from your question and your UPDATE code that the `beer_receipts` and `total_receipts` columns are your data, data which can change. The other columns identify the packy (New England for liquor store) and the date.

   Yet, when you check to see whether you have a record already you check for matches in those two *data* fields as well as the *identifying* fields. If you get different *data* from your API, your `COUNT() query will come up zero. Maybe it shouldn't have. That could cause a dup.
2. It looks like you use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to prevent duplicate records in your table. Without knowing what column or columns are in your table's primary key and any UNIQUE keys you have, it's possible you don't have the correct key to prevent your duplicates that way.

Those are two things to check out.

Also:  If this govt data is updated on a monthly schedule, why not update your copy of it with a cronjob overnight shortly after the update gets posted?  Making your users wait while you update it on demand smells to me like a future where they complain about your app being slow -- because you have to take time out to update it while they wait. Unless you're rate-limited on the API, two or three megarows overnight doesn't sound like a huge burden. Especially if your app is taking some daytime traffic off the govt API because you have a copy.

And, **edit**.

A good way to implement this might be to use two tables. Let's call one table `packy` -- sales establishment. In it:

- `packy_id` An autoincrementing id, primary key. You better use a BIGINT for that, you're in Texas after all.
- `taxpayer_name`, `location_name`. The identifiers.
- `location_address` and the other attributes

Your second table:

- `record_end_date`                         First column in the PK
- `packy_id` referring to the first table.  Second column in the PK.
- `beer_receipts`, `total_receipts` data.

This gives you the `packy_id`, an identifier of each establishment. And it lets you update your data efficiently.